# ArcObjects SQL Server Connection not recognizing instance

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcmap, arcobjects, python-2.7, comtypes

I am trying to make a connection to a SQL Server database with SdeWorkspaceFactory.  This is from my Windows 7 x64 Desktop to a Network database.

If I use this:

```
SDEWorkspace = NewObj(esriDataSourcesGDB.SdeWorkspaceFactory, esriGeodatabase.IWorkspaceFactory2)
connectionString = "server=SQLServer;" + \
                    "instance=hbffcacqsql01;" + \
                    "database=ACQ_HBED_PROD;" + \
                    "authentication_mode=OSA"

result = SDEWorkspace.OpenFromString(connectionString, 0)
```

or this:

```
connectionProperties = NewObj(esriSystem.PropertySet, esriSystem.IPropertySet)
connectionProperties.SetProperty("SERVER", "SQLServer")
connectionProperties.SetProperty("INSTANCE", "hbffcacqsql01")
connectionProperties.SetProperty("DATABASE", "ACQ_HBED_PROD")
connectionProperties.SetProperty("AUTHENTICATION_MODE", "OSA")

SDEWorkspace = NewObj(esriDataSourcesGDB.SdeWorkspaceFactory, esriGeodatabase.IWorkspaceFactory2)

result = SDEWorkspace.Open(connectionProperties, 0)
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/tstanley/Downloads/ArcMap_Python/FirstTry.py", line 88, in <module>
    result = SDEWorkspace.OpenFromString(connectionString, 0)
_ctypes.COMError: (-2147216021, None, (u'Entry for SDE instance not found in services file', u'esriDataSourcesGDB.SqlWorkspace.1', u'esri_csGeoDatabase.hlp', 0, None))
```

If I leave out the instance parameter, the connection window pops up and if I put the same value into the window, I get a connection.

[image]

Can someone tell me what I'm missing?

I have read a bunch of other posts of people with this error and they mention replacing the instance with a service number, 5151.  It seems that they are trying to connect to an SDE database, which this isn't.  I'm really new to ArcObjects so I have just about everything still to learn.

Comment: The `openFromString` method uses the old syntax, so you've got the parameters wrong.

Comment: I added another method I tried. I think this is the syntax suggested in the ArcObjects API Reference for 10.1, http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//002500000mnm000000

Comment: So follow the instructions of that link --  "SERVER" – SDE server name you are connecting to.  "INSTANCE" – Instance you are connection to.
These are not correct.  Try "INSTANCE=sde:sqlserver:hbffcacqsql01" (SERVER is ignored with Direct Connect)

Comment: Ha! You're beautiful!  It worked.  I've run into not understanding database connection strings before.  "What info goes where?"  Do you have a recomendation on where to go to brush up on this?  Many thanks!

Comment: What suggested by Vince is direct connect method as ESRI mentioned in ArcSDE documenation.It's a good method when you want to bypass SDE service and have fat clients.All sde libraries run on client.if you still want use SDE service,using propertyset is the easiest.but you must get sure your sde service is running and there is an entry for sde service in Windows/System32/drivers/etc/services in Windows on SDE runner machine.sometimes,depending on machine configuration,sde service doesn't act properly(even it's running) if there is no any entry for it in this file.

Comment: this is a successful code which i used in ArcGIS/ArcMap9.x to create a SDE workspace:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer was submitted by @Vince in the comments to the initial question.

In a direct connection the Instance parameter needs to look like this

INSTANCE = sde:sqlserver:(servername)

and the Server parameter is ignored.

More information can be found [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//002500000mnm000000)